# How do I put ant farm survival into my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm having a problem putting a map into a Minecraft server. It's a 1.7.10 map so I have the 1.7.10 server.

I have:

- Set the eula to *true*.
- Changed the map name to the map name I want.

I deleted the world. So when I start the server it says Encountered a problem while converting the player save files, retrying in a few seconds. Then it closes. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the map in a multiplayer world, there are a few steps required.

1. Load up the server once to make sure everything is working as its supposed to
2. Open up the folder the server started in and delete the folder named "world"
3. If the map you downloaded came in a zip, unzip it.
4. Rename the unzipped folder "world"
5. Drag and drop it into your server folder
6. Launch up the server and make sure everything is working properly

Source: Experience. I have done this multiple times for different servers.

Comment: I did that but all the server says is "encountered a problem while converting the player save files, retrying in a few seconds" It just keeps doing that over and over again. I even re-downloaded the server.

Comment: Did you load it up once before to make sure the server worked in the first place? Are you also sure that the map version matches the server version (1.7.10)?

Comment: Yes, I loaded it up once. The server version is 1.7.10 and so is the map. Other people have said that I have to delete a players folder. But there is no players folder.

Comment: Never mind i figured it out. I had to go into the map folder and delete the players folder.